# SQL JOIN multiple tables with limit 1

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
**clientes**
cli_clientes nome
50            A
52            B

**telefones_cliente**
cli_cliente tel_telefone
50          387
50          386
50          385
52              400


**telefones**
tel_telefone    tel_contato
385 RODOLFO - COMPRAS
386 SONIA CONTAS A PAGAR RAMAL 201
387 VANESSA CONTABILIDADE RAMAL 202
388 (null)
389 (null)
```

I need results from clientes and only the first match from telefones_cliente, AND plus tel_contato from telefones.
I just did a lot of tries so I need help, my last non working SQL:

```
SELECT
c.cli_cliente
,cli_razao_social,
tc.tel_telefone
--  ,telefones.tel_contato
  FROM
    clientes c
  JOIN telefones_cliente tc ON c.cli_cliente = (SELECT tc.cli_cliente FROM telefones_cliente, clientes c2, telefones t WHERE c2.cli_cliente=tc.cli_cliente AND tc.tel_telefone=t.tel_telefone LIMIT 1)
```

WHAT I get:

```
cli_cliente cli_razao_social    tel_telefone
50  EXACTA ENGENHARIA E ADMINISTRAÇAO LTDA  385
50  EXACTA ENGENHARIA E ADMINISTRAÇAO LTDA  386
50  EXACTA ENGENHARIA E ADMINISTRAÇAO LTDA  387
```

WHAT I need:

```
cli_cliente cli_razao_social    tel_telefone
49  WOOD FORM LTDA  384
50  EXACTA ENGENHARIA E ADMINISTRAÇAO LTDA  387
```

Comment: Your current results and expected results both include names, identifiers, and even a column name that don't appear in your sample data, which makes it hard to see what you're trying to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by , like this :

```
select clientes.cli_clients, nome , tel_telefone, tel_contato from clientes
inner join telefones_cliente on (clientes.cli_clientes =telefones_cliente.cli_cliente)
inner join telefones on (telefones_cliente.tel_telefone =telefones.tel_telefone)
group by clientes.cli_clients
```

it returns only one records for every clients

Comment: It doesn't work, this was my first try. Postgres requeri a 'group by clientes.cli_cliente, telefones.tel_telefone'

Answer (score 0):

Use 'top 1' to get only the first occurence

Try this SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a0b4c/3

This is the query I used . Gives expected result

```
select  A.clientid,B.telephone,C.Name 
from Client A inner join ClientTelephone B on A.clientid = B.clientid
inner join Telephone C on B.telephone = C.Telephone
limit 1
```

Comment: use limit 1 at the end for postgres instead of top1